# What's the difference between "build a rapport" and "build rapport"?

Tags: meaning, articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I had a look on the Internet and came across both "build a rapport" (eg. I enjoy building a rapport with customers) and "build rapport" (eg. I enjoy building rapport with customers). It seems to me "rapport" is used by native speakers sometimes as a countable noun and sometimes uncountable. What's the difference in meaning between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omitting the indefinite article in "The baby has soft skin". What rule applies here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61018/omitting-the-indefinite-article-in-the-baby-has-soft-skin-what-rule-applies-h)

Comment: The article is *optional* in *to build [a] rapport*, but [most writers ***don't*** include it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+build+rapport%2Cto+build+a+rapport&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (and in rapid *speech* it wouldn't always be easy for the audience to hear if it was present or not). It makes no difference whatsoever to the meaning.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers: adding the article makes it "an example of rapport" as opposed to "rapport as a general concept or phenomenon" but it really doesn't make any difference to meaning in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is optional in *to build [a] rapport*, but [most writers don't include it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20build%20rapport%2Cto%20build%20a%20rapport&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)...

[image]

In rapid speech it wouldn't always be easy for the audience to hear if it was present or not, but it makes no difference to the meaning in any case.